# How can I use outlined icons with react-fontawesome?

Tags: font-awesome, react-font-awesome

Basically I'm trying to use two icons:

1. `<i class="fas fa-heart"></i>`  Solid heart icon
2. `<i class="far fa-heart"></i>`  Regular heart icon (outlined)

The first one I got with the following code:

`<FontAwesomeIcon icon={faHeart} />`

**How can I get the second one?**

Answer (score 35, accepted):

After some reading in the **react-fontawesome** docs I figured out how to do outlined icons.

For the first one I need the package `@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons`
Then I need to import the icons as the following:

`import { faHeart, faTrash } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons'`

The second one, I need the package `@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons`

Then I just import the following.

`import { faHeart as farHeart } from '@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons'`

That's it!

Comment: That was what I've been looking for.

Comment: it is saying that faHeart is already decleared, any solution